# How to prevent browser back button after user logout in Jetstream?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

After logout from dashboard, when I click the back button, the dashboard window appears. Whenever i click back after logout, it should go to the home page.

Comment: Just perform a simple redirect if anyone accesses the dashboard without a valid session?

Comment: have you found a solution?